# Analogue of "simpler" for "more complex"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

The word "simpler" means "more simple", as in "This new product is simpler than the old product".

But I cannot think of a similar word for "more complex": Suppose I want to say that "This new product is **more complex** than the old product", except replacing "more complex" with just a single word. "Complexer" is not a word I am familiar with.

I did some Googling, and e.g. none of the words [here](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/more_complex.html) work. I don't mean fancier, denser, higher, etc. I mean "more complex" as in, "contains more moving parts / harder to understand and use".

Comment: See "How to form comparative and superlative adjectives" at `https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/comparative-superlative-adjectives`  You will need to find an adjective that means "complex" but falls in one of the categories there to get the "-er" form of the comparative.  Note that "simple" is in the last category where it is up to you ... say either "simpler" or "more simple".

Comment: A colloquial adjective implying complexity is "tricky".  It's trickier.

Comment: This seems an artificial constraint. Why is 'more complex' inadequate? // The lists of synonyms I've looked at don't provide a formal solution. 'Abstruser' isn't too close and sounds dire.

Comment: There are many situations where time and space are constrained (either physically or artistically) and a single word is strictly needed. I often find myself in this situation, and ironically, with this particular word in particular. For a general example, consider any sentence that includes both "simpler" and "more complex": It would flow much better and impact the reader more if "more complex" could be condensed to match "simpler" stylistically.

Comment: @TimR: This is a nice suggestion, but trickier means something slightly different. I am looking for an exact match (which sadly, might not exist).

Comment: It's simply a fact that not all adjectives have single-word comparatives and superlatives. We have simple/simpler/simplest and hard/harder/hardest, but no complex/complexer/complexest. In this case, you're forced to use "more complex" and "most complex"

Comment: It's only 2-3 more characters, is that really going to break your time/space constraints?

Comment: @Barmar: Yes. (And I am aware such a word might not exist.)